# How to strip characters interfering with Beautiful Soup returning links with specified text?

Tags: python, python-2.7, beautifulsoup, strip

I am trying to do two things with [Beautiful Soup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beautiful_Soup):

1. Find and print divs with a certain class
2. Find and print links that contain certain text

The first part is working. The second part is returning an empty list, that is, `[]`. In trying to troubleshoot this, I created the following which works as intended:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def my_funct():
    content = "<div class=\"class1 class2\">some text</div> \
        <a href='#' title='Text blah5454' onclick='blahblahblah'>Text blah5454</a>"
    soup = BeautifulSoup(content)
    thing1 = soup("div", "class1 class2")
    thing2 = soup("a", text="Text")
    print thing1
    print thing2

my_funct()
```

After looking at the source of the original content (of my actual implementation) in [SciTE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SciTE) editor. However, one difference is that there is an `LF` and four `->`'s on a new line between `Text` and `blah5454` in the link text, for example:

[image]

And therefore I think that is the reason that I am getting an empty `[]`.

My questions are:

1. Is this the likely cause?
2. If so, is the best solution to 'strip' these characters and if so what is the best way to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `text` paramater only matches on the *whole* text content. You need to use a regular expression instead:

```
import re

thing2 = soup("a", text=re.compile(r"\bText\b"))
```

The `\b` word boundary anchors make sure you only match the whole word, not a partial word. Do mind the `r''` raw string literal used here, `\b` means something *different* when interpreted as a normal string; you'd have to double the backslashes if you don't use a raw string literal here.

Demo:

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> content = "<div class=\"class1 class2\">some text</div> \
...         <a href='#' title='wooh!' onclick='blahblahblah'>Text blah5454</a>"
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(content)
>>> soup("a", text='Text')
[]
>>> soup("a", text=re.compile(r"\bText\b"))
[<a href="#" onclick="blahblahblah" title="wooh!">Text blah5454</a>]
```